# Proper Way to Release a Hugepage?

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory, mmap, huge-pages

Let's say I mount hugepages at `/mnt/hugepages`; and then two applications `open()` and then `mmap()` to the same hugepage.

After one crashes, another `close()` and then `munmap()`, I noticed the hugepage is still allocated inside `/mnt/hugepages`, `numastat -vm` also shows that a hugepage is occupied.  Then, I manually delete that file (/hugepage), `numastat -vm` still shows a hugepage is occupied.  Then, I killed the remaining application.  Finally, `numastat -vm` shows the hugepage is no longer occupied.

Now my question is what is the proper way to release the hugepage in this case without killing all the applications previously mmap-ed the page?

I did read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366181/how-to-release-hugepages-from-the-crashed-application).

But my post is different that I don't want to kill all the applications but release the hugepage asap and I don't want to unmount.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete files you need to unmap all mappings, close all file descriptors, and unlink all names.

You need to call `unlink()` on the file.